# Problema - Evento KeyDown se repite 2 veces C#

Tags: c#

Estoy practicando hacer un jueguito en C#. Y veo que manejando el evento keydown del formulario, para disparar unos misiles, se repite 2 veces este evento. No encuentro información al respecto.
Tengo un cartucho con 6 balas. Cada vez que presiono la tecla "space" me tendría que restar 1 bala y mostrar 1 bala menos en pantalla, pero cuando presiono esta tecla, y hago un seguimiento del evento, resulta que me lo repite 2 veces y en vez de mostrarme 1 bala menos, me muestra 2 menos cada vez que presiono "space". ¿Es algo particular del keydown? ¿Tengo que manejar alguna excepción cuando hace el up la tecla? porque la verdad que me estoy quedando calvo y seguro es una ganzada. Adjunto el código:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
            {
                if (contadorMisil < 6)
                {
                    switch (contadorMisil)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            misil0.Location = new Point(naveCombate.Location.X + 28, naveCombate.Location.Y);
                            misil0.Visible = true;
                            bala6.Visible = false;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            misil1.Location = new Point(naveCombate.Location.X + 28, naveCombate.Location.Y);
                            misil1.Visible = true;
                            bala5.Visible = false;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            misil2.Location = new Point(naveCombate.Location.X + 28, naveCombate.Location.Y);
                            misil2.Visible = true;
                            bala4.Visible = false;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            misil3.Location = new Point(naveCombate.Location.X + 28, naveCombate.Location.Y);
                            misil3.Visible = true;
                            bala3.Visible = false;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            misil4.Location = new Point(naveCombate.Location.X + 28, naveCombate.Location.Y);
                            misil4.Visible = true;
                            bala2.Visible = false;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            misil5.Location = new Point(naveCombate.Location.X + 28, naveCombate.Location.Y);
                            misil5.Visible = true;
                            bala1.Visible = false;
                            break;
                    }



                    if (contadorMisil < 6)
                    {
                        contadorMisil++;
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(cartuchoBalas.Text) >= 1)
                        {
                            cartuchoBalas.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(cartuchoBalas.Text) - 1);
                        }
                    }
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(cartuchoBalas.Text) == 0)
                    {
                        recargar.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Si necesitan mas información, me dicen, y voy agregando lo que me piden.

Comment: Cuando mantienes presionada la tecla keydown el evento se repite indeterminadamente, puedes colocar una bandera (una variable bool) para controlar que no lo haga (en cooperación con keyup). Yo en tu caso lo que haría sería poner un Timer para controlar la cadencia de disparos, así tendría armas con tiro a tiro, disparo continuo y además con una rapidez diferente

Comment: Voy a implementar la variable para que haga el salto el evento y ya te digo cómo me va, pero solo la presiono 1 vez, por eso me llama la atención..

Comment: Yo acabo de hacer una prueba y en mi caso tengo que mantener presionado el botón por alrededor de 1seg para que se ejecute 2 veces. Otra cosa que puede ser es que existan 2 elementos que llamen al mismo evento, o que el evento esté asignado 2 veces

Comment: Me fije bien y no hay 2 llamados al evento. Lo reescribi todo, porque total no tenia muchas cosas aun. Pero no funcionó. Tome tu idea y lo que hice fue utilizar el booleano pero con un evento keyUp para que me cancele la segunda ejecucion.. fue la unica cosa que me funciona por el momento. Gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo he tenido un problema muy parecido en una aplicación de escritorio en C# WPF.

Lo he solucionado con una variable booleana global que hace de semáforo y con la ayuda de un timer que pone a true la variable.

```
private void TbWighing_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            timer.Stop();
            
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter && habilitado)
            {
                habilitado = false;
                // Código
            }
        }
    }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            timer.Start();
        }


        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Código
            habilitado = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
```

Esta seguro que no es la solución más elegante, pero no se me ha ocurrido otra.